# What is the best way to disallow a click to highlight a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two "buttons" which are made up of a DIV with a UTF-8 arrow character in them.

When the user clicks on them, they sometimes highlight.

What is the best way suppress this highlighting so that it works in all browers but does not affect the click?

[image]

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="arrowContainer"><div class="arrowLeft">...</div></div>

.arrowContainer .arrowLeft {
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    width:15px;
    padding: 1px 0 0 0;
    height: 19px;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;   
    font-size: 9pt;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: `user-select:none` ? (not really working in older browsers)

Comment: Use `<button>` elements instead? I recommend against using divs as clickable controls because it makes the functionality inaccessible to users who can't use a mouse or other pointing device. If you can't style a `<button>` to look the way you want use an `<a>` instead and _then_ worry about preventing highlighting.

Comment: @nnnnnn text inside a button is selectable too, isn't it?

Comment: @Esailija - Yes, but only if you click outside the button and drag across it (at least in browsers I've tried it in), which the user is not likely to do by mistake while trying to click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it is selected (like when you select text), so try disabling the selection option:

```
*.notSelectable{
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

   /*
     IE 10.        
   */
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just throw all of them:

```
$.fn.unselectable = function() {
    return this.each( function() {
        $(this).css({
            mozUserSelect: "none",
            webkitUserSelect: "none",
            msUserSelect: "none",
            userSelect: "none"
        })
            .attr( "unselectable", "on" )
            .on( "selectstart", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
    });
};

$(".arrowContainer").unselectable();
```